# Tensorflow can't restore global_step from checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I can't seem to retrieve `global_step` from my saved checkpoint. My code:

```
//(...)
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file), clear_devices=True)
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
for v in tf.global_variables():
    print(v)
test = tf.get_variable("global_step")
print(test)
```

Result:

```
//(...)
Tensor("global_step/read:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
//(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line XXX, in <module>
    test = tf.get_variable("global_step")
  File "(...)/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 988, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "(...)/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 890, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "(...)/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 348, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "(...)/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 333, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "(...)/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 660, in _get_single_variable
    "but instead was +1ms." % (name, shape))
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (global_step) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

I've tried also `global_step:0` and `global_step/read:0` but with same result. Any tips? Or I shouldn't use `tf.get_variable`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `tf.get_variable` to retrieve an existing variable if that variable was created with `tf.get_variable` in the first place. Also, the variable scope must be set appropriately. It seems that here it is trying to create a new variable called `'global_step'`, indicating that it does not yet exist. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope#understanding_tfget_variable) is more information about how to use `tf.get_variable`.

I usually handle the global step like this:

```
# to create
global_step = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0), trainable=False, name='global_step')
tf.add_to_collection('global_step', global_step)

# to load
global_step = tf.get_collection_ref('global_step')[0]
# get the current value
gs = sess.run(global_step)
```

Edit: If you can't change the way you save the global step, the following should work:

```
global_step = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('global_step:0')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    predict_top_5 = tf.nn.top_k(scores, k=5)
    label_top_5 = tf.nn.top_k(input_y, k=5)
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('models')
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess,ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        global_step = int(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1])
```